# Show records where a field is NULL inside the pop-up window

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I was able to filter records that appear when we click on the `select` button inside a subpanel. It can be done by overriding the `$initial_filter` value like so:

```
public function display($widget_data, $additionalFormFields = null, $nonbutton = false) {
    global $app_strings; $initial_filter = '';
    $initial_filter.='&SOME_FIELD='.urlencode("SOMEVALUE");
}
```

That initial filter will be used as the `$_GET` parameter when the pop-up opens up so it will know which records to show

Now the tricky part is i’m trying to figure out how to filter it so it shows records where SOME_FIELD is empty… I tried something like `SOME_FIELD=null` or `SOME_FIELD=false` but it doesn’t work… If anyone can suggest anything it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to modify the list view query and data fetching logic. View following details for further help:

**For list view only**: `custom/modules/MODULE_NAME/views/view.list.php`

and following is the helping code:

```
require_once('include/MVC/View/views/view.list.php');
class MODULE_NAMEViewList extends ViewList {

    function listViewProcess() {
        global $current_user;
        $this->params['custom_where'] = ' AND module_name.name = "test" ';

        parent::listViewProcess();
}

}
```

**For list and popup view(both)**:

You need to change the logic inside `create_new_list_query` function which actually prepares a query. Some modules have override it a bean level(e.g. see `modules/Leads/Lead.php`).

If you want to override it in upgrade safe manner then create a file in custom directory e.g: `custom/modules/Leads/Lead.php`, then extend it from the core bean class like following:

```
<?php
if(!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

require_once('modules/Leads/Lead.php');
class CustomLead extends Lead {

    function create_new_list_query($order_by, $where,$filter=array(),$params=array(), $show_deleted = 0,$join_type='', $return_array = false,$parentbean=null, $singleSelect = false, $ifListForExport = false)
    { 
        // Code from create_new_list_query in and then modify it accordingly. 
    }
}
```

Register new bean class in this location: `custom/Extension/application/Ext/Include/custom_leads_class.php` and registration code will look like following:

```
<?php
$objectList['Leads'] = 'Lead';
$beanList['Leads'] = 'CustomLead';
$beanFiles['CustomLead'] = 'custom/modules/Leads/Lead.php';
?>
```

Comment: I've since went on to do it differently because i couldn't figure it out but thank you for taking the time to write such a detailed reply. I will definitely give this a try in the future.